# Querying two tables to filter data using select case

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, filtering

I have two tables
Table 1 looks like this

```
ID  Repeats
-----------
A   1
A   1
A   0
B   2
B   2
C   2
D   1
```

Table 2 looks like this

```
ID  values
-----------
A   100
B   200
C   100
D   300
```

Using a view I need a result like this

```
ID  values  Repeats
-------------------
A   100 NA
B   200 2
C   100 2
D   300 1
```

that means, I want unique `ID`, its `values` and `Repeats`. `Repeats` value should display NA when there are multiple `values` against single `ID` and it should display the `Repeats` value in case there is single value for `repeats`.

Initially I needed to display the max value of `repeats` so I tried the following view

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[BookingView1]
AS
SELECT bv.*, bd2.Repeats FROM Table1 bv 
JOIN
(
    SELECT distinct bd.id, bd.Repeats FROM table2 bd
    JOIN
    (
      SELECT Id, MAX(Repeats) AS MaxRepeatCount
      FROM table2
      GROUP BY Id
    ) bd1
    ON bd.Id = bd1.Id
    AND bd.Repeats = bd1.MaxRepeatCount
) bd2
ON bv.Id = bd2.Id;
```

and this returns the correct result but when trying to implement the `CASE` it fails to return unique `ID` results. Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `outer apply`:

```
select t2.*, t1.repeats
from table2 t2 outer apply
     (select (case when max(repeats) = min(repeats) then max(repeats)
                   else 'NA'
              end) as repeats
      from table1 t1
      where t1.id = t2.id
     ) t1;
```

Two notes:

- This assumes that `repeats` is a string.  If it is a number, you need to cast it to a string.
- `repeats` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I'm including another approach that will work if `repeats` is `NULL`. However, [Gordon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36777051/4437524) answer has a much simpler query plan and should be preferred.

**Option 1** (Works with `NULL`s):

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID, t2.[Values], 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'NA' 
        ELSE CAST(MAX(Repeats) AS VARCHAR(2)) 
    END Repeats
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.Repeats
        FROM #table1 t1
    ) t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, t2.[Values]
```

**Option 2** (does not contain explicit subqueries, but does not work with `NULL`s):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.ID, 
    t2.[Values], 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(t1.Repeats) OVER (PARTITION BY COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Repeats), t1.ID) > 1 THEN 'NA' 
        ELSE CAST(t1.Repeats AS VARCHAR(2)) 
    END Repeats
FROM #table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, t2.[Values], t1.Repeats
```

**NOTE:** 
This may not give desired results if `table2` has different `values` for the same `ID`.